# No space left on device alert for mod_security

Tags: apache, mod-security

Following error in mod_security error log:

> /var/lib/mod_security/default_SESSION": No space left on device

We are using DETECTION_ONLY.

```
ls -lh /var/lib/mod_security
total 11M
-rw-r----- 1 daemon daemon 8.6M Mar 12 02:13 default_SESSION.dir
-rw-r----- 1 daemon daemon 118G Mar 12 03:24 default_SESSION.pag
The folder size is 11M showing but the file inside this is showing 118G.
```

What may be the reason? Since it already writing to log, what is the purpose of default_SESSION file? Can we prevent write to this file?

Comment: This is issue and only workdaround is to manually delete that file, check here some conversation might be linked to similar problem you have got : https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/var-cpanel-secdatadir-ip-pag-file-massive.565591/ and I also found https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBCS-234

Comment: What is version of mod-security you are using, it might be the case you need to downgrade that?

Comment: check the disk space in `/var` : `df -hs /var`

Comment: mod_sec version is 2.9